# List windows in irssi

Tags: irssi

How to list windows in irssi? I'm looking for the equivalent of `:ls` in vim (which lists the buffers).

For example, if I want to switch to a specific window (channel that I've joined), I have to search for it with `ctrl-n` and `ctrl-p`, sometimes switching through ~10 windows in the process. It would be preferable to list the windows with their titles and indeces, so that I could switch simply with `alt-[index]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nei, whose alias is in the other answer, suggested using [iko_switcher](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shabble/irssi-scripts/master/ido-mode/ido_switcher.pl). It requires [uberprompt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shabble/irssi-scripts/master/prompt_info/uberprompt.pl). Instructions on how to load and autoload scripts can be found [here](https://github.com/shabble/irssi-docs/wiki/Guide#LOADING-AND-UNLOADING-SCRIPTS).

iko_switcher uses an interactive search dialog in the bottom bar that let's you do something similar to fuzzy searching (but it's called flex mode), and has a host of other interesting features. Its biggest advantage over Nei's alias in the other answer is that it doesn't polute the chat area.

Answer (score 6):

## `/win list`

The command `/win list` yields something like this:

```
20:56 Ref  Name                 Active item     Server          Level
20:56 1    (status)                             Freenode        ALL
20:56 2                         #dailyminutes   DM              
20:56 3                         #lhspodcast     Freenode
```

Answer (score 1):

On #irssi @freenode, user named 'vague' gave an alias that prints the index and window's name:

```
/alias listwinanditems script exec print join" ",map{"\cD4/".$$_->{refnum}.":(\cD3/".((join"\cD6/,\cD3/",map$$_->{name},$$_->items)||$$_->get_active_name)."\cD4/)"}sort{$$a->{refnum}<=>$$b->{refnum}}Irssi::windows
```

He referred to it as [Nei's](http://anti.teamidiot.de/nei/2006/10/neis_web_dump_1/) alias.

I gave this alias the shorter name `ls`. So the usage is to switch to first window (`alt-1`) and enter `/ls`.